# Please can somebody explain why I can't put my int inside my input?

Tags: python

I would just like for somebody to explain why the int inside the input for the string 'cont' wont work. Here is the complete program:

```
import random
ans1=("Go for it!")
ans2=("No way, Jose!")
ans3=("I’m not sure. Ask me again.")
ans4=("Fear of the unknown is what imprisons us.")
ans5=("It would be madness to do that!")
ans6=("Only you can save mankind!")
ans7=("Makes no difference to me, do or don’t - whatever.")
ans8=("Yes, I think on balance that is the right choice.")
print("Welcome to MyMagic8Ball.")
question = input("Ask me for advice then press ENTER to shake me.\n")
print("shaking ...\n" * 4)
cont=input(int("Continue? Yes = 1, No = 0.\n"))
choice=random.randint(1, 8)
while cont != 0:
    if choice==1:
        answer=ans1
    elif choice==2:
        answer=ans2
    elif choice==3:
        answer=ans3
    elif choice==4:
        answer=ans4
    elif choice==5:
        answer=ans5
    elif choice==6:
        answer=ans6
    elif choice==7:
        answer=ans7
    else:
        answer=ans8
print(answer)
```

Comment: you want `int(input())` not `input(int())`

Answer (score 4):

Because you can't cast a string containing non-numeric characters to an int, as simple as that. What you're currently doing is converting a non-integer string into an integer.

```
input(int("Continue? Yes = 1, No = 0.\n"))
```

It should instead be

```
int(input("Continue? Yes = 1, No = 0.\n"))
```

Note this would work as long a string containing only integer characters is passed as an input, so be prepared for some exception handling.

Comment: That's exactly what `int()` does—it converts a string to an integer.

Comment: It isn't quite that simple. You definitely can convert a string to an int. `int('33')` works just fine.

Comment: It doesn't when what you are converting string contains non-integer characters, or am I wrong?

Comment: No thats correct. Your very first answer submission was very poor though. Now its a lot better, if not the best...

Answer (score 3):

@A.Chandu already gave you the answer, and I know this isn't [codereview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I can't help myself to add this:

This code:

```
ans1=("Go for it!")
ans2=("No way, Jose!")
ans3=("I’m not sure. Ask me again.")
ans4=("Fear of the unknown is what imprisons us.")
ans5=("It would be madness to do that!")
ans6=("Only you can save mankind!")
ans7=("Makes no difference to me, do or don’t - whatever.")
ans8=("Yes, I think on balance that is the right choice.")
```

could be written as:

```
answers = [
    "Go for it!",
    "No way, Jose!",
    "I’m not sure. Ask me again.",
    "Fear of the unknown is what imprisons us.",
    "It would be madness to do that!",
    "Only you can save mankind!",
    "Makes no difference to me, do or don’t - whatever.",
    "Yes, I think on balance that is the right choice.",
]
```

so that this:

```
if choice==1:
    answer=ans1
elif choice==2:
    answer=ans2
elif choice==3:
    answer=ans3
elif choice==4:
    answer=ans4
elif choice==5:
    answer=ans5
elif choice==6:
    answer=ans6
elif choice==7:
    answer=ans7
else:
    answer=ans8
```

can become this:

```
answer = answers[choice-1]
```

you still have to somehow support the case when `choice` is less than 1 or greater than 8.

Also please look at [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice).

Answer (score 2):

Simple you are trying to change the string into Integer. You're calling a invalid function inside input. because you cannot change the string that contains non-numeric characters so its invalid.

Change

```
cont=input(int("Continue? Yes = 1, No = 0.\n"))
```

to

```
cont=int(input("Continue? Yes = 1, No = 0.\n"))
```